# Convert result json to different format javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on the application where i need to convert the response json into different format and pass it to different API . I am finding it hard to convert the desired structure.

Input :

```
var value = `[
    {
    "PRODUCT_GROUP": "Accessories",
    "MATERIAL_GROUP": "S98",
    "MATERIAL": "300154",
    "MATERIAL_DESC": "BLOCKS", 
    "PP_AD": 45.7,
    "PP_DISC_OLD": 34.7      
    },
    {
    "PRODUCT_GROUP": "Accessories",
    "MATERIAL_GROUP": "S98",
    "MATERIAL": "000000000000300155",
    "MATERIAL_DESC": "PALLET",
    "PP_AD": 123.7,
    "PP_DISC_OLD": 43.7  
    }, 
    {
    "PRODUCT_GROUP": "Accessories",
    "MATERIAL_GROUP": "S99",
    "MATERIAL": "300155",
    "MATERIAL_DESC": " WOODEN",
    "PP_AD": 23.7,
    "PP_DISC_OLD": 23.7  
    }
    ]`;
```

I need to convert this to Result mentioned below.

OUTPUT:

```
{
    "categoreies": [{
            "PRODUCT_GROUP": "Accessories",
            "MATERIAL_GROUP": "S98",
            "categoreies": [{
                "MATERIAL": "300154",
                "MATERIAL_DESC": "BLOCKS",
                "PP_AD": 45.7,
                "PP_DISC_OLD": 34.7
            }, {
                "MATERIAL": "000000000000300155",
                "MATERIAL_DESC": "PALLET",
                "PP_AD": 123.7,
                "PP_DISC_OLD": 43.7
            }]
        },
        {
            "PRODUCT_GROUP": "Accessories",
            "MATERIAL_GROUP": "S99",
            "categoreies": [{
                "MATERIAL": "300155",
                "MATERIAL_DESC": " WOODEN",
                "PP_AD": 23.7,
                "PP_DISC_OLD": 23.7
            }]
        }
    ]
}]
```

I tried to loop the code and form an object but getting the desired result.

Kindly help.

```
value=JSON.parse(value);
let firstobj={},arr1=[],secobj={},arr2=[],finalobj={};
value.forEach((items)=>{
    firstobj.PRODUCT_GROUP=items.PRODUCT_GROUP;
    firstobj.MATERIAL_GROUP=items.MATERIAL_GROUP;

    arr1.push(firstobj);

    secobj.MATERIAL=items.MATERIAL;
    secobj.MATERIAL_DESC=items.MATERIAL_DESC;

    arr2.push(secobj);

    finalobj.CATEGORIES=arr2;

     console.log(finalobj)
})
```

Could you please help me in converting the input json to result json

Comment: You forgot to ask a _question_.

Comment: @zerkms: Need to convert the input json to result json.

Comment: A question is not the expression of a need or a wish. It typically has a question mark.  What is the *specific* programming-related problem that you encountered while trying?

Comment: @trincot I am not able to convert to the desired format. which needs to be passed to the API. if you could guide how to convert to the desired format.

Comment: ". if you could guide how to convert to the desired format." --- start with something simpler: take one item from the original array, and convert one of its properties to the desirted format. Just one property of one object. Can you do that? If not - what is the exact problem you have with that little problem now?

Comment: sub-array `categoreies` is each object entry grouped by `MATERIAL` ?

Comment: yes @DanStarns.Header is materialgroup and subarray is materials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a key for each entry that is the combination of the product and material group (for example as JSON). Then create a Map with those keys and with arrays as values, initially all empty. Then iterate over the data to populate those arrays. Finally convert that Map to the target structure.

```js
let value = `[{"PRODUCT_GROUP": "Accessories","MATERIAL_GROUP": "S98","MATERIAL": "300154","MATERIAL_DESC": "BLOCKS","PP_AD": 45.7,"PP_DISC_OLD": 34.7},{"PRODUCT_GROUP": "Accessories","MATERIAL_GROUP": "S98","MATERIAL": "000000000000300155","MATERIAL_DESC": "PALLET","PP_AD": 123.7,"PP_DISC_OLD": 43.7},{"PRODUCT_GROUP": "Accessories","MATERIAL_GROUP": "S99","MATERIAL": "300155","MATERIAL_DESC": " WOODEN","PP_AD": 23.7,"PP_DISC_OLD": 23.7}]`;

let arr = JSON.parse(value).map(({PRODUCT_GROUP, MATERIAL_GROUP, ...rest}) => 
    ({ group: JSON.stringify({PRODUCT_GROUP, MATERIAL_GROUP}), rest})
);
let map = new Map(arr.map(({group}) => [group, []]));
arr.forEach(({group, rest}) => map.get(group).push(rest));
let result = Array.from(map.entries(), ([group, categories]) =>
    ({...JSON.parse(group), categories})
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var value = `[
    {
    "PRODUCT_GROUP": "Accessories",
    "MATERIAL_GROUP": "S98",
    "MATERIAL": "300154",
    "MATERIAL_DESC": "BLOCKS", 
    "PP_AD": 45.7,
    "PP_DISC_OLD": 34.7      
    },
    {
    "PRODUCT_GROUP": "Accessories",
    "MATERIAL_GROUP": "S98",
    "MATERIAL": "000000000000300155",
    "MATERIAL_DESC": "PALLET",
    "PP_AD": 123.7,
    "PP_DISC_OLD": 43.7  
    }, 
    {
    "PRODUCT_GROUP": "Accessories",
    "MATERIAL_GROUP": "S99",
    "MATERIAL": "300155",
    "MATERIAL_DESC": " WOODEN",
    "PP_AD": 23.7,
    "PP_DISC_OLD": 23.7  
    }
    ]`;
 

value = JSON.parse(value);

let outputobj = {};
outputobj.categories = [];

let tmpdict = {};


value.forEach((items)=>{ 
 
 if (!tmpdict[items.MATERIAL_GROUP]){
  tmpdict[items.MATERIAL_GROUP] = {
   "PRODUCT_GROUP" : items.PRODUCT_GROUP,
   "MATERIAL_GROUP" : items.MATERIAL_GROUP,
   "categories" : []  
  }
 }
 let tmpobj = {
  "MATERIAL" : items.MATERIAL,
  "MATERIAL_DESC" : items.MATERIAL_DESC,
  "PP_AD" : items.PP_AD,
  "PP_DISC_OLD" : items.PP_DISC_OLD 
  
  }
 
 tmpdict[items.MATERIAL_GROUP].categories.push(tmpobj);  
      
 
})

for (let key in tmpdict){
 outputobj.categories.push(tmpdict[key]);
}

console.log(outputobj);
newJSON = JSON.stringify(outputobj);

console.log(newJSON);
```